# Android Gallery Image Adapter onItemClickListener does'nt get called and other issues

Tags: android, android-gallery

am using the following code to trigger on clicking an image in a gallery

```
                holder.imgPostImagesGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    //handle clicks
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                        System.out.println("Iamge adapter clicked");
                        /*Show ImageViewerfragment*/
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ImagePagerActivity.class);
                        //Generate Image Array first
                        String[] urls=new String[1];
                        urls[0]=feedsTableList.get(position).post_content.images.get(position).toString();
                        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, urls);
                        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, 0);
                        startActivity(intent);  
                    }                       
                });
```

Image Adapter Code

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ArrayList<String> images;
    private Context mContext;       
    public ImageAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<String> arrayImages) {
        mContext = c;
        images=arrayImages;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    //http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/image-gallery-example-in-android/
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(320, 320));          
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black_button);
        imageLoader.displayImage(images.get(position), imageView, options);
        //Add tap listeners
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        return imageView;

    }



}
```

The gallery works fine, but nothing happens on clicking/tapping an image.

And also, i seem to be having an issue with gallery scrolling, it just does'nt seem right. Scrolling lags and at times does'nt scroll at all. I am using this along with SlidingMenu library.

**Update**:

As mukesh pointed, i had 2 click events which i missed. But removing them also did'nt help; but adding my own clicklistener helped

```
//click listener for gallery
private class galleryPhotoClickListener implements OnItemClickListener{    
    private Context context;

    public galleryPhotoClickListener(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ImagePagerActivity.class);
        //Generate Image Array first
        String[] urls=(String[]) feedsTableList.get(position).post_content.images.toArray();
        urls[0]=feedsTableList.get(position).post_content.images.get(position).toString();
        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, urls);
        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, 0);
        startActivity(intent);  

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use only one 1  or 2

```
1.  holder.imgPostImagesGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    //handle clicks
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                        System.out.println("Iamge adapter clicked");
                        /*Show ImageViewerfragment*/
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ImagePagerActivity.class);
                        //Generate Image Array first
                        String[] urls=new String[1];
                        urls[0]=feedsTableList.get(position).post_content.images.get(position).toString();
                        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, urls);
                        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, 0);
                        startActivity(intent);  
                    }                       
                });



    or



  2. imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks, that along with writing an independent click listener helped.Updated my question with answer